# Formalisation of distance algorithm

Tags: programming

I am trying to formalise a small algorithm and I have difficulties writing it in mathematical terms properly.

I have a vector $d$ with $d = 1, \dots, N$ and a vector $c$ with $c = 1, \dots, C$.

What my algorithm is doing is to compute a distance matrix one $d$ at a time, recursively.

I would like to express the idea of

$dist(d_{i},c_{j})$

one $d_{i}$ at a time.

In the end I end up with a matrix ($M = N \times C$).

For instance, would the following notation be correct to express this idea

\begin{equation}
M = \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{C} dist(i,j)
\end{equation}

From a programming point of view, it is simply

```
for (i in 1:N) {
  for (j in 1:C){
    mat[i,j] =  dist( t[i], c[j] )
  }
}
```

Does the sign $\sum$ denotes directly `for i in ...`? And does the order of the sign $\sum$ matter formally, like it matter in the programming example?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum$ means "sum". What you seem to miss here is a proper way to handle **indices**.

Let's make a parallel with informatic :

- A vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ corresponds to a (one dimensional) float array of length $n$. Say this vector is $v$, one writes $v_i$ for the $i$th component of $v$, this corresponds to $v$[$i$] in most computer languages.
- A $M\times N$ matrix corresponds to a (two dimensional) float array of shape $(M,N)$.
- In math, the "for" is often implicit. For example, if we want a vector $v$ whose components are the square of numbers up to 10, one will write $$v:=(i^2)_{1\leqslant i \leqslant 10}$$

Likewise for matrices, in your case the matrix will be written
$$M := (dist(t_i,c_j))_{{1 \leqslant i \leqslant N},\,{1\leqslant j \leqslant C}}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. But with this notation how to you distinguish between comparing all the $t_{i}$ and all the $c_{j}$ with each other, like in any regular distance matrix computation and the specific example I gave? Also, what does the `:=` means, compared to $=$?

Comment: The notation "$:=$" comes from informatics, it means "defined to be equal to", as in C.